# unable to push back a pointer into vector

Tags: c++

I have created a pointer class called `p_pointer` and created a vector to hold the `p_pointer` type. However, when I tried to use the `push_back` function it did not work. I have tried to directly use `double*` instead of `p_pointer (double)` and the `push_back` function does work that way. So my guess is something is wrong with my copy constructor?

```
template<class T>
class p_pointer{
private:
    T* cp;
    size_t* refptr;

public:
    //default constructor
    p_pointer() : cp(0), refptr(new size_t(1)){}

    //copy constructor
    p_pointer (p_pointer&s) : cp(s.cp), refptr(s.refptr){
        *++refptr;
    }

    //assignment operator
    p_pointer& operator=(const p_pointer& s){
        ++*s.refptr;
        //freeing the left hand size if it is the last one
        if(--*refptr == 0){
            delete cp;
            delete refptr;
        }
        cp = s.cp;
        refptr = s.refptr;
    }

    //other assignment operator
    p_pointer& operator=(T* s){
        if(--*refptr == 0){
            delete cp;
            delete refptr;
        }
        cp = s;
        refptr = new size_t(1);
    }

};


int main()
{
    p_pointer<double> temp;
    temp = new double(1);

    std::vector<p_pointer<double> > collection;
    collection.push_back(temp); //error at here
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the error message?

Comment: shouldn't `p_pointer (p_pointer&s)` be `p_pointer (const p_pointer&s)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "copy constructor" actually is not copy constructor:

```
//copy constructor
p_pointer (p_pointer&s):cp(s.cp),refptr(s.refptr){
*++refptr;
}
```

it should accept `const ref`, instead of `ref`

Valid copy constructor is:

```
//copy constructor
p_pointer (const p_pointer&s):cp(s.cp),refptr(s.refptr){
*++refptr;
}
```

---

Also there is compilation error in

```
//other assignment operator
p_pointer&operator=(T* s){
```

It should return something, `*this` for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering, your solution does work... a follow up question, i always thought that const is just us promising that we wont change the const parameter in the function. Thus, it would be nice to declare the parameter as const but not necessary to do so. However in this case, you have shown that the code only work with const added. Is this just the case for copy constructor or am i getting something wrong?

Comment: @Esther _Is this just the case for copy constructor?_ yes, copy constructor works only with `const`. For another cases (methods, custom contructors, etc) you are free to choose, when to use `const`